# ZSH completion: show folders first

Tags: zsh-completion

How to give the highest priority to the folders group on tab complete? Right now, during the completion (no `cd` in front), almost everything is placed before folder names, so it's a bit of annoying to iterate through system commands, functions, etc. just to get into a folder. There is no overridden `zstyle` in my `.zshrc`.

Example:
[image]

Comment: To be clear: You mean completion of the first word on the command line?

Comment: @Adaephon example attached.